# How do I calculate correlations using einsum?

Tags: numpy

I've got a numpy tensor `X` of shape `(1075, 252, 487)`.

For each of the 1075, I want to calculate the correlation matrix `X.T@X`, so I'm left with a tensor of shape `(1075, 487, 487)`.

How do I write this as an Einstein summation?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the other answer, but avoiding the extra transpose, you can do the following:

```
(N, R, C) = (20, 15, 30)
X = np.random.rand(N, R, C)
cors = np.einsum("ikj,ikl->ijl", X, X)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

(N, R, C) = (20, 15, 30)
X = np.random.rand(N, R, C)
cors = np.einsum("ijk,ikl->ijl", X.transpose((0, 2, 1)), X)
```